# Как принудительно перезагрузить шрифт в Хроме?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, шрифты

Есть html-страница с кастомным шрифтом. По некоторым причинам сервер может этот шрифт не отдать. В таком случае надо перезагрузить шрифт *без изменения адреса*.

Я ожидал, что удаление и повторное добавления всех стилей решит проблему.
Оказалось, что в гуглохроме это не работает. Как починить?

Пример кода для тестирования (сервер на nodejs): https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JeBp/hcaRZgGSC

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Font test</title>

<script>document.cookie = 'send-the-font=0'</script>

<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(ArefRuqaa-Regular.ttf);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa';
  font-style: normal;
  color: blue;
}
</style>

<p>Just some text</p>

<button id="retry">Retry</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('retry').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.cookie = 'send-the-font=1';

  var style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

  for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
    style[q].remove();
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
      document.head.appendChild(style[q]);
    }
  }, 1000);
}); 
</script>
```

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var file = decodeURIComponent(request.url.substr(1));
  var headers = {};

  console.log(file);

  switch(file) {
    case "":
    case "index.html":
      file = "index.html";
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
      break;

    case "favicon.ico":
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/x-icon';
      break;

    case "ArefRuqaa-Regular.ttf":
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'font/opentype';

      if (request.headers.cookie && request.headers.cookie.indexOf('send-the-font=1') !== -1) {
        console.log('  allowed');
        break;
      }

      /* Falls through */

    default:
      console.log('  404');
      response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('Not found!');
      return;
  }

  fs.stat(file, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('An error occured while loading file information :(');
    } else if (!data.isFile()) {
      response.writeHead(403, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response.end('Not a file');
    } else {
      headers['Content-length'] = data.size;
      response.writeHead(200, headers);
      fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response);
    }
  });
}).listen(8081);
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/41324990/4928642)

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь хотел прояснить, что это за причины, почему это вдруг сервер не отдал шрифт и насколько это легитимная ситуация. Возможно, стоит не облегчать симптомы, а заниматься лечением болезни?

Comment: я только что у себя на компе создал директорию и подключил всякие шрифты , 3 штуки , разные и не из google font , все шрифты из локальной папки и предварительно воспользовался сервисом online : https://onlinefontconverter.com/  дабы из ttf сделать полный комплект , архив подключил к html и шрифты заработали , вот скриншот : https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2bcD/FvBE5bqUa , возможно у вас не подключено верно

Comment: @Geyan, внимательнее. Сервер в примере первый раз намеренно отдаёт 404 вместо шрифта. А вопрос заключается в том, как в таком случае заставить Хром повторить запрос без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41324990/4928642

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324990/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, хром как-то запоминает содержимое тега style и при повторном появлении стиля с таким же содержимым (неважно, того же самого, или нового) не посылает запрос за шрифтами.

Чтобы устранить эту проблему, надо изменить содержимое тега style:

```
document.getElementById('retry').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.cookie = 'send-the-font=1';

  var style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

  for (var q=0; q<style.length; ++q) {
    style[q].innerHTML += " ";
  }
});
```